# Howto handle unreleased bugs?

Tags: bug-tracking, bugzilla

Bugzilla, the tool we use for bug-tracking, provides the usual bug attributes <sup>[1]</sup> like:

- Version - when a bug became evident
- Target milestone - when a bug has been fixed (or should be fixed)

Now **I found a bug** that probably arose from fixing several other bugs in a uncoordinated team work under pressure, **that isn't released yet**. This bug is annoying but not as important as the bugs I already work on, and it's not just a tiny one that I could fix on-the-fly or keep in mind easily, as my mind is full. I mean: **I cannot fix it right now.** I already know that some rework must be done to resolve it (the project is already "saturated" with quick fixes), also sub-bugs will surely be found. That's why I think it's definitely dedicated to our bug tracker.

For some bigger releases, we usually add pseudo-versions for internal use, but now, that I'm between two minor releases, I feel a little be lost with this approach.

What is the experienced way for dealing with "unreleased bugs"?

---

<sup>[1]</sup> there are of course also keywords, whiteboard etc.